# what's the difference between "external" and "internal" about ethtool transceiver's type?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

there're two ubuntu 16.04 machines,the one ethtool transceiver's type is :internal,the other one shows external. Two machines ping status are fine.
I find ethtool man docs explain it :
"nternal|external
Selects  transceiver type. Currently only internal
and external can be specified, in the future  fur‐
ther types might be added."
but i can't understand it ,so , what's the difference between "external" and "internal" about ethtool transceiver's type?

[image: ethtool transceiver's type]

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question and came across this thread without any answer so I will jolt down what I learn from my own googling and answer I got from peer. Please be mind that my knowledge to NIC and transceiver are limited so please correct me if there's any mistakes.

In linux kernel source code, I found there's a macros called XCVR_INTERNAL and XCVR_EXTERNAL, where XCVR stands for transceiver.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4d6d4c7f541d7027beed4fb86eb2c451bd8d6fff/include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h#L1965

The comments describes the macros as such:

> #define XCVR_INTERNAL     0x00 /* PHY and MAC are in the same package */
>
> #define XCVR_EXTERNAL     0x01 /* PHY and MAC are in different packages */

PHY and MAC in this context is a chip for Ethernet physical in NIC, where PHY converts signal received from the cable to bits and sends to MAC through [MII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface) to assemble it as a packet ([more details I got from this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/75620/340089)).

The "same package" (ie. internal) means the PHY, MAC, and MII are integrated as a one chip, whereas "different package"(external), PHY and MAC are independent chips that's connected by MII.

There are two different types of transceiver exists because there are instances where NIC want to have more than one-to-one connection between PHY and MAC, meaning there could be multiple PHY connects to single MAC and vice versa.

Hope this help with anyone who comes across this question.